# Google Chrome - Name Window via API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use the Name Window function quite a bit in Chrome to name many of my open Chrome windows.

[image]

This works well, but I was wondering if there is a way to control this using the API?  Is there a way to manage these names from an extension?  For example, I use the Spaces extension, and it would be great if it could update the Chrome Window Name when you give your 'space' a name. Here you can see a few named spaces, but I have to manually update the window names to match the spaces.

[image]

If it's possible somehow, I can look at making my own extension like Spaces, or suggest it to the creator of the spaces extension etc.

I had a look at the Chrome API's but I couldn't see anything, but I'm still hopeful!

Cheers,

Comment: Not yet: https://crbug.com/1190160

Answer (score 2):

Window naming is a really handy feature, and programmatic access to it is on their radar, but a low priority feature request. You can subscribe to this bug to get info on when it starts to progress: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1190160